# Loading value from properties file using Spring Expression Language in Mule

Tags: java, mule

I have a properties file that contains a path value that I want to load in for use within my program.

I have the following in my XML

```
<flow doc:name="Flow1" name="Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message."
        doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
        port="8081" contentType="text/html" />
    <custom-transformer class="com.test.app.mule.ReadFile" doc:name="Java">
        <spring:property name="path" value="${key.path1}" />
    </custom-transformer>
```

and the following in my java code (which loads a file from the specified path from the properties file)

```
public class ReadFile extends AbstractMessageTransformer {


    private String path;


    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     * loads the content of the file specified in the parameter
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            the name of the file
     * @return the content of the file
     * 
     * 
     */

    public String readFile(String filename, String filePath) {

        File file1 = new File(path, filePath);
```

This works fine however I am wondering is there any way to modify what I have to allow for the use of the @value annotation

`private @Value("${key.path1") String path;` and get rid of the setters and getters?

Mule doesn't seem to play nice when doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the properties on the spring:

[Mule ESB:Context Property Placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130038/mule-esbcontext-property-placeholder)

[Mule- Access spring property placeholder inside groovy component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110261/mule-access-spring-property-placeholder-inside-groovy-component)

[property placeholder in mule configuration is resolved from one file but not from the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074625/property-placeholder-in-mule-configuration-is-resolved-from-one-file-but-not-fro)

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-properties

Comment: On the spring? That's very vague, none of the links provided help with this issue.

Comment: What you trying to do is to access the properties by annotation. The way I know is configure the context place holder on the Mule and then inject the property by @Value. I will find an example to post here.